# How to inject services into a provider with angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service, angularjs-provider

In every piece of information I can find (including the angular documentation), the way to inject a service into a provider is through the `$get` method:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.provider('helloWorld', function() {
    this.$get = function() {
        return {
            sayHello: function() {
                return "Hello, World!"
            }
        }
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope, helloWorld) {    
    $scope.hellos = [helloWorld.sayHello()];
}
```

This would work perfectly in **angular 1.2** and below: http://jsfiddle.net/1kjL3w13/

Switch to angular **1.3** though, and the `$get` function completely breaks. It seems that whatever's returned from the `$get` function is no longer used to instantiate the provider, and thus is now useless for injecting f.e. services.

Same example as above, but using **angular 1.3**: http://jsfiddle.net/duefnz47/

This is exactly the behavior provided in the angular documentation. So either the documentation is wrong or I've completely misunderstood it. I don't really care if the `$get` method works as before or not though, I just need to be able to inject services reliably into my provider.

Comment: check my answer hope it help you :).

Comment: Services, factory, constants, values, etc are not supposed to be injected into providers...rather they are done so on the factory that the provider exposes...

Comment: @deostroll this is for building providers with different purposes but that can share methods and content between then. Think one "shared" provider with base functions that gets injected into many other providers. Does your statement still hold in that scenario? Also, the service that needs to be injected is f.e. the $window service, because I do need access to that inside my provider. And it does need to be a provider to be injectable in the `config` method.

Comment: This can be done with `angular.injector()`. but not sure about 1.3 support...

Comment: Would it be mockable if I use `injector` straight up in my provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are using global controller which is not valid according to angular 1.3

So use

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope, helloWorld) {    
    $scope.hellos = [helloWorld.sayHello()];
});
```

Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duefnz47/2/)

**

[Migration Document official](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/guide/migration)

**
Hope it help :)

Comment: Thanks, this solved this issue, sadly it was an abstraction that's probably a bit too abstracted to really be indicative of my actual problem. With so many levels of complexity it's hard to come up with a simple example that exhibits the behavior. I'm still having the issue in my actual code which does not use a global controller. I'll set it as answered since you did solve this particular issue though.